# Auto Increment ID based on 2 columns

Tags: mysql, insert, table, phpmyadmin, auto-increment

I have table called Logs. it has 4 columns `ID, USER_ID, USER_TYPE, USER_ACTION`

where
`USER_ID` is unique 
`USER_TYPE` is unique for every `USER_ID` and 
`USER_ACTION` can be anything `1,2,3 or A to Z.`

`USER_ID` is parent. 
`USER_TYPE` is child. 
`USER_ACTION` is grandchild.

When `USER_ID, USER_TYPE and USER_ACTION` is inserted I want to auto incriment ID column. 
see sample data. I tried my best to as simple as possible to explain.

[image]

Comment: How can User_Id be unique when you have multiple rows with the same value ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Such a feature does _not_ exist in InnoDB.  I discuss workarounds in http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb#index_issue_2_column_pk

Comment: @RickJames Thank you, is there any downside of using Myisam? @RohitGupta sorry `USER_ID` can be any other number well.

Comment: @ZohebPatel - For starters, it only works with 2 columns, not 3.  If that were not a problem, there are still other problems: ACID, crash recovery, etc.  This forum is littered with discussions advocating InnoDB over MyISAM.